# Prove there's $\left|A-B\right| = \aleph$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

> Let A a set such that $\left|A\right| \ge \aleph$. Prove there's a $B\subseteq A$ such that $\left|B\right|\ge \aleph$ and $\left|A-B\right| = \aleph$.

Lets assume there's a $B\subseteq A$ such that $\left|B\right| = \aleph$ (are we allowed to assume that?)

$A-B \subseteq A$ implying $\left|A-B\right| \le \aleph \le \left|A\right|$

I don't know how to continue. There must be some rule or theorem I'm missing..

I'd be glad for help.

**Note:** $\aleph$ is the cardinality of thecontinuum.

Comment: By definition, $|A|\ge\aleph$ means there is an injection from $\mathbb R$ into $A$, and the image of this injection can be your "$B\subseteq A$ such that $|B|=\aleph$". However this tells you nothing about the size of $|A-B|$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Or its complement, maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Let $ f : \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow A$ an injective function.

Then consider simply $B= A \setminus f(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: That $B$ is not necessarily large enough to satisfy $|B|\ge\aleph$. (Consider $A=\mathbb R$ and $f$ being the identity).

Comment: That's a nice thought anyway, @Crostul

Comment: However $B=A\setminus f([0,1])$ should be ...

Comment: The argument works well if $|A|>\aleph$; something more is needed if $|A|=\aleph$.

Comment: Isn't @HenningMakholm idea solves the issue @egreg?